# How do I use jQuery to append a variable (image tag) to the current div I'm currently in?

Tags: jquery, html, variables, append, this

I am having the user enter a specific keyword, which will return an image that matches that keyword (Instagram API). When the user enters a keyword in the text area and presses the submit button, I want the fetched image to be placed within the same div as the text area that was used.

Here are my two divs:

```
<div id="firstPic" class="pic">
    <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
        <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="FAVORTIE ANIMAL"/>
        <input type="submit" onclick="instaSearch();"/>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="secondPic" class="pic"></div>
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="FAVORITE INSECT"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="instaSearch();"/>
</form>
```

Here is the function being called:

```
function instaSearch() {
  //user input
  var tagname = document.getElementById("input").value;

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'+tagname+'/media/recent?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT-ID&callback=YOUR-CALLBACK',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(result){
      for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        var url = result.data[i].images.thumbnail.url;
        var instapic = '<img src="' + url + '"/>';
            $(this).append(instapic);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Everything appears to work correctly until **$(this).append(instapic);**. Ideally, I would like to append **instapic** to THIS div.

Any help here is much appreciated!!

Comment: where is it supposed to be inserted? Your html isn't consistent for the 2 `class="pic"`. Also there are no `<textarea>` shown either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the same ID more than once in a page so you need to change to using classes. I would suggest you forget about using `onclick` since you are already using jQuery

```
<div id="firstPic" class="pic">
    <form class="pic_form" >
        <input type="text" class="search_input" placeholder="FAVORTIE ANIMAL">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
// document ready function
$(function () {
    // use submit handler instead of button to allow keyboard submit
    $('form.pic_form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // `this` is the form that was submitted
        var tagname = $(this).find('.search_input').val();
        var $container = $(this).parent();
        var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + tagname + '/media/recent?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT-ID&callback=?'
        // $.getJSON is shortcut method for `$.ajax`
        $.getJSON(url, function (result) {
            $.each(result.data, function (_, item) {
                var url = item.images.thumbnail.url;
                var instapic = '<img src="' + url + '">';
                $container.append(instapic);
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped A LOT.